# Recommended way to do Dependency Injection with CoreData managed objects?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Given that I have a class managed by the CoreData stack,
I am currently writing a Framework, and I want to be able to create my objects through dependency injection (ideally, only through DI).

I am also designing with "fail fast" mentality (i.e. crash as soon as possible), and following closely SOLID principles.

That framework will be iOS 9-10 compatible, and could be used in either ObjC and Swift (or mixed targets), therefore I ideally do not want to rely on non cross compatible features in either ObjC or Swift.

This piece of code is meant to be used internally, and not exposed to the consumer of the framework as [Jonah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/552822/jonah) points out that exposing such functionalities is not a very solid choice.

### Question :

I have here 2 different ways to create my object, and I am not sure if
either of them are corrects, if there is a "preferred" solution, or one that has less pitfalls in usage ?

Here is a code snippet to illustrate my case :

```swift
import CoreData
class Example: NSManagedObject {}

class DependencyClass: NSObject {}

extension Example
{
    public convenience init(with someDependency:DependencyClass,
                            context:NSManagedObjectContext)
    {
        let description = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Example", in: context)
        self.init(entity: description!, insertInto: context)
        //Configure the result object here
    }

    class func NotAConvenienceInit(with someDependency:DependencyClass,
                       context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Example
    {
        let selfClassName = String(describing: self)
        let result = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: selfClassName, into: context) as! Example
        //Configure the result object here
        return result
    }
}

let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
let dependency = DependencyClass()

//Usecase A
let myExample = Example(with: dependency, context: context)

//Usecase B
let anotherExample = Example.NotAConvenienceInit(with: dependency, context: context)
```

I have been thinking about failable initializers for the convenience init, I am quite seduced by the idea that once the init method is over, I am "guaranteed" my object is valid. I think both ways can guarantee that through various mechanisms.

Apple seems to prefer `+insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` in [their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html) and that is why I came up with those 2 methods.

PS : I'm still learning Swift, my apologies in advance if this seems like an already solved question. After reading many articles on various websites, I did not find a conclusive solution, and therefore am turning to SO.

Comment: If your framework will be used with obj-c as well, you could combine your two methods using a common pattern in objc-c, factory class methods. In your class method just return an instance of the managed object by calling the convienence init. If the framework doesn't need to be used with obj-c I would just use the init. Also, in my opinion failable inits sound like a good idea considering you want dependency injection. I'm currently in class so I can't give an extremely detailed answer but, I'll come back later with a detailed answer.

Comment: I edited my question following your comment, I will experiment with your suggestion and see where it leads, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to do the same thing and my conclusion was that it's better to avoid this approach and instead keep behavior, especially behavior which requires other dependencies off of the models.

Why?

1. Swift and Objective-C really don't give you any tools to prohibit the use of existing constructors so while you can provide alternatives with your DI arguments there's very little you can do to ensure that `NSManagedObject` or `NSEntityDescription` are not used to create instances of your model.
2. Additionally `NSManagedObject.init(entity:insertInto:)` and `NSEntityDescription.insert​New​Object(for​Entity​Name:​into:​)` are used to insert new model instances but are not the only ways in which instances of your model classes can be created. Take a look at `NSManagedObject`'s `awake​From​Fetch()` and `awake(from​Snapshot​Events:​)` (and `awake​From​Insert()`).

   Suppose I create a `NSFetchedResultsController` with a fetch request returning one of your framework models. If I call `controller.fetchedObjects` I'll get instances of your model. Similarly I could execute a `NSFetchRequest` directly. You might use a singleton container to supply dependencies in an `awake...` implementation but that limits the creating code's ability to specify those dependencies and leads to another problem:
3. Managed object context queues. Since `NSManagedObjects` are tied to a content and must be used on that context's queue you need to watch out for dependencies introducing access to a model on the wrong queue and often want dependencies scoped to a particular context.

Instead I'd consider:

- Have your framework return non-NSManagedObject models which are (perhaps immutable) snapshots of state from your Core Data store. If you can avoid exposing use of Core Data to consumers of your framework then you can give them models which are not constrained to a particular concurrency queue and you can completely own the lifecycle of these models.
- Avoid any external dependencies in models and move such behavior into service classes or other interfaces which can then use DI more easily. Make sure these service classes respect the concurrency queue of any models they are given so all of your interfaces will probably need to be asynchronous.

Comment: I completely agree with everything you said.
As a matter of fact, I never planned to expose the CoreData stack to consumers, and indeed only returning POCOs to them.
This code is not meant to be exposed outside the framework.

With this consideration in mind, is there anything inherently *wrong* with my solution or jonathan's (above comment) suggestion ?

Comment: I updated slightly the description of my conundrum to reflect your points, thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach, just beware of cases even internally where you create these models via fetch requests if you expect them to still have these dependencies.