# Trying to setup Core Data stack using Dependency Injection

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on a project right now that uses Core Data.  However, it is NOT used by the RootViewController.  The first ViewController in my app is the Registration or the Login screens.  It is ONLY after the user has either registered or logged in, will they be taken to the initial screen of the app which requires Core Data (and thus, the ManagedObjectContext).  The Core Data stack that I would like to use is as follows:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer!
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        createContainer { container in
            self.persistentContainer = container
            let storyboard = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard
            guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootViewController") as? RootViewController
                else { fatalError("Cannot instantiate root view controller") }
            vc.managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        }
        return true
    }

    func createContainer(completion: @escaping (NSPersistentContainer) -> ()) {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyDataModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
           guard error == nil else { fatalError("Failed to load store: \(error)") }
           DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(container) }
        }
    }

}
```

My question is, how do I setup my Core Data stack, and via dependency injection, bypass the the first View Controllers which are responsible for logging in/registration, and assign the value of the ManagedObjectContext to the property of the ViewController which requires it (which is UITableViewController)?  Also keep in mind that I'm not using storyboards, so the above approach also needs to be modified to eliminate it's use.

Comment: I am assuming you mean to say that you are using dependency injection for `NSManagedObjects` here are a few reasons why this is not a popular way of doing things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187929/recommended-way-to-do-dependency-injection-with-coredata-managed-objects Instead prefer a lazily instantiated Core Data Singleton Class that handles core data operations. Think about it this way, why would you use DI when you could write an extension to your NSManagedObject that fulfills the dependency. You should try to avoid any external dependencies to your NSManagedObject.

Comment: What's the point of putting all of this thought into configuring Core Data in a  way that is not what 99.9% of all other apps do? Just create it in the App Delegate and configure the first View Controller with it. If the first VC doesn't want to use it, it doesn't have to.

Comment: Singletons are bad and create tightly coupled code which is difficult to maintain, nearly impossible to test and very hard to refactor. Dependency injection solves those issues. Lazily loading Core Data is a recipe for poor performance.

Comment: This is covered in Apple's Core Data documentation here: developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/… "Pass a Persistent Container Reference to a View Controller In your app’s root view controller, import Core Data and create a variable to hold a reference to a persistent container. Return to your app’s delegate. In application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:), downcast the app window’s rootViewController to your app’s root view controller type. In this reference, set the root view controller’s container property to the persistent container."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The app delegate should inject the context (or the container of the context) into the root view controller.
2. The root view controller should inject the context into its children.

Even though the root view controller doesn't use the context does not mean it cannot be responsible for the dependency injection.

I would pass the container straight through the root view controller.

Comment: That means if the rootViewController is a UINavigationController or a UITabBarController then we'd have to subclass them and add the context property in each of them. Is that right?

Comment: @AkshitZaveri Usually no. I normally write logic to look for those two cases and when they are discovered ask them for their root or array of view controllers and then pass off the MOC to the next level instead.  No need to subclass for that one use case.

Comment: That's also a good idea. So, each of the UIViewController instances will have a `context` property which can then be passed to the `ViewModels` in order to use the CoreData APIs.

Comment: Well I wouldn't use a viewModel with a gun to my head but you get the general idea yes :)

Comment: Interesting. Why would not you use a ViewModel?

Comment: View Model is part of MVVM which is not part of MVC that iOS is designed around. A view model is a redundant class. Everything that gets put into a view model properly belongs either in a controller (not necessarily a view controller), or a view.

Comment: I agree. But, for higher unit testing coverage purpose and better separation of concerns, the view model would be a good option.

Comment: Nope,MVVM does not help with any of that at all, it just adds more noise. But that is straying far outside of the answer to this question.  If you want to discuss MVVM there are plenty of places for that.

Comment: Again, I agree with you. Could you please send me in the right direction? Probably a link? Thank you so much.

Comment: View controllers handle lifecycle, views handle display, data models handle data anything else goes into the appropriate controllers (business, network, etc.) and dependency injection binds everything together. KISS principle applies :) Clever is bad.

Comment: @EricMentele I trust you realize that your comment says the same thing that my answer does.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Oh... doh!! This comment pointing out Apple's documentation belongs on the question, not your answer. Thanks for pointing that out! Your book is great by the way! https://pragprog.com/book/mzcd3/core-data-in-objective-c-third-edition